# Xamarin ios and android payment gateway in browser

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, payment-gateway

I am using Xamarin for mobile development.

I have a requirement to integrate a payment gateway with the app. Chosen payment gateway has a web interface only.

Is there a way i can use this payment gateway, like opening up a webclient and then using web view to make transactions and then provide a redirect url of the app so that success/failed transactions can be redirected to the app and then i can show data that has been bought ?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you developing a Xamarin.Forms application or separate Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS apps?

Comment: Separate Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS apps

Comment: Yes you can use webview for that. I'm not familiar with iOS, but for Xamarin.Android. You can [call C# from Javascript](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/webview/call_csharp_from_javascript/).

Comment: Do you have examples that I can look at ?